# Using KeyValuePair in VB.NET for a reverse lookup capable dictionary (example hint in C# needs converting)

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, generics, keyvaluepair, reverse-lookup

I'm currently on a VB.NET project and wish to use a KeyValuePair to facilitate a reverse lookup.

I've found a great example in C# here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic78080.htm, however I am having a small problem converting to VB.NET (both manually and using a translator (online carlosag)). For example the syntax I would expect in the Add method is as follows:

```
    Public Sub Add(ByVal key As TKey, ByVal value As TValue)
        Me.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Tkey(key, value))
    End Sub
```

Whereas this tells me *"Too few type arguments to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)'"*

Any assistance would sure be helpful (indeed as would a full translation of the example including anon methods :D.

Comment: That implementation isn't worth converting TBH. It exhibits O(n) performance for both find-by-key and find-by-value. Even just using a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` you'll get better performance characteristics with O(1) for find-by-key and O(n) for find-by-value. If you need O(1) for both then write a wrapper that contains a forward and reverse dictionary. Don't just blindly copy code from forums without understanding it.

Comment: Thanks, Greg, very valuable advice. In this instance I'm not too concerned about the performance, since the dictionary will only contain ~20 items, and be very rarely searched. I simply want to keep things clean and tidy in implementation and didn't think it would be this hard in vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by making the Add method Overloads as such:

```
Public Overloads Sub Add(ByVal key As TKey, ByVal value As TValue)
   Me.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)(key, value))
End Sub
```

Strange that although MyBase.Add works (found via a decompile in Reflector) Me didn't (despite "this" working in C#). I guess I put this down to a quirk in VB.NET?

Thanks Kevinw and Meta-Knight. Original code was wrong, but I was inheriting from List all along.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the example you referred to through the tool I usually use to convert C# to VB.NET at www.developerfusion.co.uk/tools

```
Imports System 
Imports System.Collections.Generic 
Imports System.Text 
Namespace ConsoleApplication1 
    Class PairCollection(Of TKey, TValue) 
        Inherits List(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)) 
        Public Sub Add(ByVal key As TKey, ByVal value As TValue) 
            Me.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)(key, value)) 
        End Sub 
        Public Function FindByKey(ByVal key As TKey) As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)) 
            Return Me.FindAll(Function(ByVal item As KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)) (item.Key.Equals(key))) 
        End Function 
        Public Function FindByValue(ByVal value As TValue) As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)) 
            Return Me.FindAll(Function(ByVal item As KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)) (item.Value.Equals(value))) 
        End Function 
    End Class 
    Class Program 
        Private Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String()) 
            Dim menu As New PairCollection(Of String, Double)() 
            menu.Add("Burger", 3.5R) 
            menu.Add("Hot Dog", 2.25) 
            menu.Add("Fries", 1.75) 
            Console.WriteLine(menu.FindByKey("Fries")(0)) 
            Console.ReadLine() 
        End Sub 
    End Class 
End Namespace
```

As you can see, the Add() method comes out very slightly differently to yours.

Comment: Thanks, that looks better but I still get error: 
<i>Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)' cannot be converted to 'TKey'</i>

Answer (score 0):

1- As kevinw pointed out, your original code is just wrong, it should be:

```
Me.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)(key, value))
```

2- The code above should insert a new `KeyValuePair` in a `PairCollection` which inherits from `List(Of KeyValuePair)`. If it doesn't work, there's a good chance that your Inherits line is wrong. According to the error, the `Add` method expects a key, not a `KeyValuePair`... maybe your inherited from a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`?